# re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, devops, nano-server

I wan,t create simple asp.net core application and deploy it to windows server 2016 docker container.

This is My server OS and I pulled latest nanoserver base image

[image]

And when I trying to pull app it gives me error?:
[image]

[image]

I read about [os compability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) but not understand what is wrong.

The default asp.net core application docker file looks like

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
```

How I must change it for my virtual server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem changing version, final version of docker look like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-nanoserver-sac2016 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["App8/App8.csproj", "App8/"]
RUN dotnet restore "App8/App8.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/App8"
RUN dotnet build "App8.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App8.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App8.dll"]
```